# OPENSSL RAND_bytes output isn't reliable

Tags: c, linux, openssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having trouble trying to generate random arrays with the `RAND_bytes()` function from OPENSSL.

OPENSSL version:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018)
built on: Tue Nov 12 16:58:35 2019 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-kxN_24/openssl-1.1.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
```

generate_salt.c

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint8_t *generate_salt()
{
    uint8_t *res = malloc(16 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    RAND_bytes(res, 16);
    return res;
}

void print_hexa(uint8_t *message)
{
    int message_length = 0;
    while (message[message_length] != '\0')
    {
        message_length += 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < message_length; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", message[i]);
    }
    printf(";\n");
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        print_hexa(generate_salt());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
05b3c470b709ef345b;
862c53a9;
1aa1665fe26aa04a7cdc9e63a14b8859;
e093b250e55172c6a12eb21a14146b52;
7de470cf708249bd81571a9fe1362618;
7fccff3509fb0189a954784ce198e3cd;
ba98881d1023a5f4d4c5a2c829ce26c3;
63e0f027a057de8f0e32e595f7cd4df2;
6faa5ab05413c5566a3b05783dfaa086;
ae2e91741d0dabd6ba7d0ae55885540f;
cd49f8c218cfdaf02dfd6fa53e523e51;
2fd24cb9e2d6e7b992eb28a2ffa5af44;
5c6f6ffb62784c87cc25ba25c6ba;
56a0cc97d008ee65b0b6f78eb094fcee;
9d1ef2ef40966dca1991364fa83d134d;
2ab61566cdd9a0d2bf09b2634b112cd2;
7064ffe72ccb9f9eb2954c0c59477fd8;
100e0c34e64d2f6f788c6fe7b908b181;
67bb8b232d1ab2ada5632c0e5fbb0f4f;
f55df4049bf0c477fdf6121399e5c116;
```

My problem is that some of the results aren't of the given length (16 bytes). I have similar issues with the functions I'm using from the `openssl/evp.h` module. I first thought I had some memory leak related issues, which is why I made a seperate `generate_salt.c` file which seems to prove me wrong.

Has anyone ever met this and knows how to solve it?

I am using WSL (Linux Bash on Windows), which might be another reason for it not to work properly. Perhaps OPENSSL requires an actual Linux kernel.

EDIT: As suggested in the accepted answer, the implementation of `print_hexa` is wrong. The while condition leads to display errors when the 0x00 byte appears in the byte array (and may cause segfault as well). The length should either be given as argument or hard coded in the function.
There is no way of getting the *length* of a pointer in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `print_hexa` is wrong. Random bytes may contain `0x00` and the function may stop there.
Even worse thing is that if the random bytes don't contain `0x00`, it will do out-of-range access to find `0x00`.

To avoid this issue, the length to print should be given to `print_hexa` separately.

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint8_t *generate_salt()
{
    uint8_t *res = malloc(16 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    RAND_bytes(res, 16);
    return res;
}

void print_hexa(uint8_t *message, int message_length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < message_length; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", message[i]);
    }
    printf(";\n");
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        print_hexa(generate_salt(), 16);
    }
}
```

Another choice is hard-coding the length as you did in the `generate_salt` function.

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint8_t *generate_salt()
{
    uint8_t *res = malloc(16 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    RAND_bytes(res, 16);
    return res;
}

void print_hexa(uint8_t *message)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", message[i]);
    }
    printf(";\n");
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        print_hexa(generate_salt());
    }
}
```

Defining the length as macro is better than writing the magic number `16` directly.

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 16

uint8_t *generate_salt()
{
    uint8_t *res = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(uint8_t));
    RAND_bytes(res, LENGTH);
    return res;
}

void print_hexa(uint8_t *message)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", message[i]);
    }
    printf(";\n");
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        print_hexa(generate_salt());
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `RAND_bytes` *can* fail, OP should check the return value and act accordingly.